# null pointer exception in java servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I got a "null pointer exception" fault in java servlet. Could someone tell me what happens? And how to avoid that?

I know java servlet can be used as part of a hybrid solution, could support many different programming languages. How would the different programs execute/call each other and exchange information? (could someone tell me some words but codes). In addition, values extracted from a session object have to be converted(cast) to a specific type, but why?

For example, how can I store a variable of type "int" in a session object. Could someone help me to figure it out?

Comment: Kudos on packing so many disparate questions into one paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I got a "null pointer exception" fault in java servlet. Could someone tell me what happens? And how to avoid that?*

That happens when you're trying to access/invoke some reference which is actually `null`.

```
SomeObject someObject = null;
someObject.doSomething(); // Throws NullPointerException.
```

You need to make sure that you only access/invoke it when it is **not** `null`.

```
SomeObject someObject = null;
if (someObject != null) {
    someObject.doSomething(); // Won't throw NullPointerException.
}
```

It's just matter of logical thinking and understanding [basic Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

---

> *Another thing, I know java servlet can be used as part of a hybrid solution, could support many different programming languages. But how would the different programs execute/call each other and exchange information?(could someone tell me some words but codes).*

Pass them as method parameter(s).

---

> *In addition, values extracted from a session object have to be converted(cast) to a specific type, but why? For example, how can I store a variable of type "int" in a session object. Could someone help me to figure it out?*

Use [`Integer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) instead and/or profit Java 1.5's [autoboxing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) capabilities.